# LaTeXのtikzで頂点の文字が重なってしまう

Tags: latex

LaTeXで頂点の文字が重なって描画されてしまうのですが,なぜでしょうか？

```
\documentclass[dvipdfmx]{ltjsarticle}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate[label=left:A](A)at(0,0)
    \coordinate[label=right:B](B)at(3,0);
    \coordinate[label=above:C](C)at(2,2);
    \draw(A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: 出力結果]

Answer (score 0):

こちらの環境でもラベルABCが重なる現象が再現しました。
`\documentclass[dvipdfmx]{ltjsarticle}`を`\documentclass{ltjsarticle}`に変更したところ現象は解消しました。

原因の詳細は不明ですが、`[dvipdfmx]`が影響しているのだと思います。
実行したツールは`lualatexです。

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.17.0 (TeX Live 2023)

The LuaTeX team is Hans Hagen, Hartmut Henkel, Taco Hoekwater, Luigi Scarso.

LuaHBTeX merges and builds upon (parts of) the code from these projects:

tex       : Donald Knuth
etex      : Peter Breitenlohner, Phil Taylor and friends
omega     : John Plaice and Yannis Haralambous
aleph     : Giuseppe Bilotta
pdftex    : Han The Thanh and friends
kpathsea  : Karl Berry, Olaf Weber and others
lua       : Roberto Ierusalimschy, Waldemar Celes and Luiz Henrique de Figueiredo
metapost  : John Hobby, Taco Hoekwater, Luigi Scarso, Hans Hagen and friends
pplib     : Pawe\l Jackowski
fontforge : George Williams (partial)
luajit    : Mike Pall (used in LuajitTeX)

Compiled with libharfbuzz 7.2.0; using 7.2.0
Compiled with libpng 1.6.39; using 1.6.39
Compiled with lua version 5.3.6
Compiled with mplib version 2.02
Compiled with zlib 1.2.13; using 1.2.13

Development id: 7581
```